# How to make java API wrapper work with different function arities?

Tags: clojure, arity

I'm writing a small wrapper for a Java API, and I create a listener like this

```
(defn conv-listener [f]
  (proxy [com.tulskiy.keymaster.common.HotKeyListener] [] (onHotKey [hotKey] (f))))
```

Is there a way in which I can make this work whether the function `f` accepts 1 or zero arguments. (Ie. if `f` does not accept arguments, just call it with `(f)`, if it accepts an argument - which will be the value of the hotkey in this case - call it with `(f hotKey)`)?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769005/functions-overloaded-with-different-number-of-arguments

Comment: That is not a duplicate question, or even related to this one.

Answer (score 4):

No. Just call `(f hotKey)` all the time, and if someone wants to use a function that ignores `hotKey` then they can just pass  something  like `(fn [_] (...do whatever...))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we ended up solving it (pull request from Nic Marsh):

```
(defn arg-count [function]
  "Counts the number of arguments the given function accepts"
  (let [method     (first (.getDeclaredMethods (class function)))
        parameters (.getParameterTypes method)]
    (alength parameters)))

(defn call-with-correct-args [function & args]
  "Call the given function on all given args that it can accept"
  (let [amount-accepted (arg-count function)
        accepted-args   (take amount-accepted args)]
    (apply function accepted-args)))

(defn- conv-listener [function]
  "Takes a function with one argument, which will get passed the keycode, and creates a listener"
  (proxy [com.tulskiy.keymaster.common.HotKeyListener] []
    (onHotKey [hotKey] (call-with-correct-args function hotKey))))
```

http://github.com/houshuang/keymaster-clj