# Why is Clojure's complement function defined as a multi-arity function?

Tags: clojure

Here is the implementation of the Clojure's `complement` function:

```
(defn complement
  "Takes a fn f and returns a fn that takes the same arguments as f,
  has the same effects, if any, and returns the opposite truth value."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [f]
  (fn
    ([] (not (f)))
    ([x] (not (f x)))
    ([x y] (not (f x y)))
    ([x y & zs] (not (apply f x y zs)))))
```

Why is it defined as a multi-arity function? The following implementation, it seems to me, would achieve the same result:

```
(defn alternative-complement [f]
  (fn [& args] (not (apply f args))))
```

For what reason, does the Clojure's `complement` treat none, single and two arguments as "special cases"?

Comment: Maybe because it is easier for the compiler to optimize the specific cases of 0, 1 and 2 arguments? Thereby avoiding the runtime overhead of working with a sequence.

Comment: Exactly for that reason. There are many other examples of such an approach in `clojure.core`.

Comment: It was added
[here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/b8e333fb3437dca760f16136ed074a4dd463fe35#diff-313df99869bda118262a387b322021d2cd9bea959fad3890cb78c6c37b448299L838-R855) and it is to be expected, that it is an optimization.

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked before here, but I can't find it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769005/functions-overloaded-with-different-number-of-arguments is close.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, when you use Java's variable arguments feature, the compiler
[creates an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746663/how-does-jvm-implement-the-varargs) for the arguments. There is a [performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426455/javas-varargs-performance) associated with this array creation.

In order to eliminate this performance penalty, specific arities are added for the most commonly used cases, optimizing for these. If it can be determined through some means that `complement` is used on functions which take zero, one or two arguments, most of the time, then it's deemed worth the effort to add specific arities for zero, one, and two argument functions. Functions which take more than two arguments are supported but may incur a minor performance penalty.

Java's own core library makes use method overloading to eliminate the performance hit of varargs. See Java 11's [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) which contains twelve overloads for the static `of` method, maxing out at allowing [ten elements](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/List.java#L1004).

```java
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9, E e10) {
    return ImmutableCollections.listFromTrustedArray(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5,
                                                         e6, e7, e8, e9, e10);
}
```